# Regex: i am writing a regular expression to match substring and return rest of the part of url

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

i have a url something like `http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2` on which perforing regex which checks for `bill` and returns the rest part of the url i.e `bill/part1/part2`

Below the code which i am trying to make work
`"http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2".match(/^bill\:(.*)$/gm)`

**Answer**

With validation `("http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2".match(/bill(.*)$/gm) || [])[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just match anything after (and including) `bill`:

```js
console.log(
  'http//:www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2'
    .match(/bill(.*)/)[0]
)
```

But using proper URL parsing with the `URL` object (see [answer by guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48335449/3928341)) or a library like [url-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-parse) would likely be a better approach:

```js
console.log(
  urlParse(
    'http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2'
  ).pathname.slice(1)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/url-parse@latest"></script>
```

Comment: How can we remove the query strings ? `http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2?p=xyz`. if we want to ignore the `?p=xyz`

Comment: You can just split on `?` and take the first part, `result.split('?').shift()`

Answer (score 2):

You use `URL` constructor and can check `.pathname` of the URL

```js
let url = new URL("http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2");
if (/\/bill\//.test(url.pathname)) console.log(url.pathname.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing *front carat* `^` and `\:` worked for you

**Explanation**

- `bill` to match string starting from `bill`
- `(.*)$` matches rest of the input till *end of string*

**Demo**

```js
var output =   "http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2".match(/bill(.*)$/gm)
console.log(output);
```

Comment: how can query string can be ignored ?

for `http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2?p=xyz`

Comment: By splitting the result with `?` and taking first item.

Comment: splitting the a secondary options. i am looking something which can be done using the same regex

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `^bill\:(.*)$` does not match `bill/part1/part2` because you use an anchor `^` to assert the position at the start of the string.
You also specify `\:` after `bill`, but : is not present after bill in the example.

If you want to return `bill/part1/part2`, you could use [`bill.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/ABFVYF/1) without the capturing group `(.*)`.

```js
var match = "http://www.abc.def/bill/part1/part2".match(/bill.*$/);
console.log(match[0]);
```